# Native Base Input Full Width

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, but I can't set the input to take 100% of the parent `VStack` view:

[image: input]

My `Input` is wrapped inside a `FormControl`, and it should take the whole width of the parent `VStack`, but it doesn't. I tried adding `flex={1}`, `width="100%"` and `alignSelf="stretch"`, but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
    <VStack space="md" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <LottieView
        source={success}
        style={lottieStyle(200, 200).container}
        autoPlay
        loop={false}
      />

      <Heading numberOfLines={2} textAlign="center">
        Connected to {alias}!
      </Heading>

      <Input name="walletName" label="Name your wallet" />
    </VStack>
```

My `Input` is simply a wrapper:

```
    <FormControl isInvalid={hasErrors(name, touched, errors)}>
      {label && <FormControl.Label>{label}</FormControl.Label>}
      <NBInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
        onBlur={handleBlur(name)}
        {...rest}
      />
      <FormControl.ErrorMessage leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}>
        {errorMessage(name, touched, errors)}
      </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
    </FormControl>
```

What I want to achieve is set the `FormControl` as a whole to take all the width space of its parent component

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue based on the information you provided but was unable to. Here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@md-rehman/formcontrol---width-issue) I was playing with.

But still, I ask you to try a few things which might solve your problem.

1. Add `w='100%'` on VStack.
2. Remove `alignItems` from VStack.

If these 2 thing doesn't solve it, please share a snack because we might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve it: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4589